# Swing: How to code "set colors" for the text from the user side?

Tags: java, swing, colors, set, jtextcomponent

I must do project for studies (homework) where We upgrade utilities.
One my feature is "coloring text".

I never did It, but I have small idea. I want to bind for example *$0 to $9* with colors: `BLUE,RED,BLACK,WHITE...` (screen shot). When I confirm setting "$x" isn't visible but text must have changed color.

I need something information, article or something to learn how to do It.
I know, I must do new class with constructor of colors and 2nd class where I have multi-line text and single line text where I should implement this colors -that's all.

Thanks for each help. Regards.

PS. Sorry for my not perfect English

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVruZ.jpg

[image]

Classes where I should implement this option with colors:

```
package com.horstmann.violet.product.diagram.propertyeditor.baseeditors;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

    import com.horstmann.violet.product.diagram.property.text.LineText;
    import com.horstmann.violet.product.diagram.property.text.MultiLineText;

    /**
     * A property editor for the MultiLineText type.
     */
    public class MultiLineTextEditor extends LineTextEditor
    {
        protected void setSourceEditor()
        {
            this.source = (MultiLineText) getValue();
        }
        protected LineText getSourceEditor()
        {
            return this.source;
        }
        protected JTextComponent createTextComponent()
        {
            return new JTextArea(ROWS, COLUMNS);
        }

        protected JComponent createScrollPanel(JTextComponent textComponent)
        {
            return new JScrollPane(textComponent);
        }

        private MultiLineText source;

        private static final int ROWS = 5;
    }


    package com.horstmann.violet.product.diagram.propertyeditor.baseeditors;

    import com.horstmann.violet.product.diagram.property.text.LineText;
    import com.horstmann.violet.product.diagram.property.text.SingleLineText;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

    public class SingleLineTextEditor extends LineTextEditor
    {
        protected void setSourceEditor()
        {
            this.source = (SingleLineText) getValue();
        }
        protected LineText getSourceEditor()
        {
            return this.source;
        }
        protected JTextComponent createTextComponent()
        {
            return new JTextField(COLUMNS);
        }

        private SingleLineText source;
    }

    public abstract class LineTextEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport
    {
        protected abstract void setSourceEditor();
        protected abstract LineText getSourceEditor();
        protected abstract JTextComponent createTextComponent();

        public boolean supportsCustomEditor()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public Component getCustomEditor()
        {
            setSourceEditor();
            final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(getTextEditorComponent());
            return panel;
        }

        private JComponent getTextEditorComponent()
        {
            if (this.textEditorComponent == null)
            {
                final JTextComponent textComponent = createTextComponent();

                textComponent.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, tab);
                textComponent.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, shiftTab);

                textComponent.setText(getSourceEditor().toEdit());
                textComponent.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
                {
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
                    {
                        getSourceEditor().setText(textComponent.getText());
                        firePropertyChange();
                    }

                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
                    {
                        getSourceEditor().setText(textComponent.getText());
                        firePropertyChange();
                    }

                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
                    {
                    }
                });
                this.textEditorComponent = createScrollPanel(textComponent);
            }
            return this.textEditorComponent;
        }

        protected JComponent createScrollPanel(JTextComponent textComponent)
        {
            return textComponent;
        }

        protected JComponent textEditorComponent;

        protected static final int COLUMNS = 30;

        protected static Set<KeyStroke> tab = new HashSet<KeyStroke>(1);
        protected static Set<KeyStroke> shiftTab = new HashSet<KeyStroke>(1);
        static
        {
            tab.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"));
            shiftTab.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift TAB"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This terribly hard to do in Java, but it isn't easy either.  Do you really need to do this for the assignment?  Or it something extra you are trying to do?

Comment: One way to do this is many Swing components support HTML (a very basic version of HTML, don't expect all the latest features).  Tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html